# awk/sed - replace column with pattern using variables from other columns

Tags: awk, sed

I have a tab delimited text file:

| #CHROM | POS | ID | REF | ALT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 188277 | rs434 | C | T |
| 20 | 54183975 | rs5321 | CTAAA | C |

and I try to replace the "ID" column with specific patern $CHROM_$POS_$REF_$ALT with sed or awk

| #CHROM | POS | ID | REF | ALT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 188277 | 1_188277_C_T | C | T |
| 20 | 54183975 | 20_54183975_CTAAA_C | CTAAA | C |

unfortunately, I managed only to delete this ID column with:

sed -i -r 's/\S+//3'

and all patterns I try do not work in all cases. To be honest I am lost in the documentation and I am looking for examples which could help me solve this problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to replace the tabular representation of your input/output with your actual textual input/output so we can see for sure what your fields contain (e.e. maybe they're quoted, maybe not, maybe they have surrounding blanks, maybe not, we can't tell from tables) and copy/paste it to test with.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk, you can set the value of the 3rd field concatenating field 1,2,4 and 5 with an underscore except for the first line. Using `column -t` to present the output as a table:

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
NR>1 {
  $3 = $1"_"$2"_"$4"_"$5
}1' file | column -t
```

Output

```
#CHROM  POS       ID                   REF    ALT
1       188277    1_188277_C_T         C      T
20      54183975  20_54183975_CTAAA_C  CTAAA  C
```

Or writing all fields, with a custom value for the 3rd field:

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
NR==1{print;next}
{print $1, $2, $1"_"$2"_"$4"_"$5, $4, $5}
' file | column -t
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU `sed` solution

```
sed '2,$s/\(\S*\)\t\(\S*\)\t\(\S*\)\t\(\S*\)\t\(\S*\)/\1\t\2\t\1_\2_\3_\4_\5\t\4\t\5/' file.txt
```

Explanation: from line 2 to last line, do following replace: put 5 `\t`-sheared columns (holding zero or more non-whitespace) into groups. Then replace it with these column joined using `\t` excluding third one, which is replace by `_`-join of 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th column.

*(tested in sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2)*

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1 {print $0}; NR>1 {print $1, $2, $1"_"$2"_"$4"_"$5, $4, $5}' inputfile.txt
```